# Which is the right way to introduce data in Android's calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to make a calendar but I'm having some problems with it. I have all the information I need such as the day, the month, the hour, etc, but when I try to create the calendar it says that the application suddenly stopped. When I debug and look the LogCat, the error returned is: "Failed to find provider info for calendar" and it appears between the Checkpoint2 and the Checkpoint3.

The code to create the event when I have all the information is the next one:

```
    private void crear()
{
    Log.d("Crear Evento","Checkpoint 1");
    this.alarm = 1; //ALARMA!!!!
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(this.anyo,this.mes,this.dia,this.hora,this.minutos,0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    long endTime = startTime+3600000;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    Log.d("Crear Evento","Checkpoint 2");
    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this)+"events");

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) ),new String[] { "calendar_id", "displayname" }, null,null, null);
    Log.d("Crear Evento","Checkpoint 3");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // fetching calendars name
    String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    // fetching calendars id
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    Log.d("Crear Evento","Checkpoint 4");
    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    Log.d("Crear Evento","Cálculos previos sin problemas");
    event.put("calendar_id", String.valueOf(CalIds[0]));
    event.put("title", this.titulo);
    event.put("description", this.descripcion);
    event.put("eventLocation", this.lugar);
    event.put("allDay", 0);
    event.put("eventStatus", 1);
    event.put("transparency", 0);
    event.put("dtstart", startTime);
    event.put("dtend", endTime);
    event.put("hasAlarm", this.alarm);
    try{
        contentResolver.insert(eventsUri, event);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("Crear Evento", "¡Guardado sin problemas!");
}
```

Comment: Please, do yourself a favour.  Stop trying to use logcat to find errors and learn to use the debugger.  You will save yourself a whole lot of time and learn a vital skill.  To give you something to Google for, put a breakpoint on the first line of the method, start your app as debug, then step through each line watching what the code does.

Comment: Apparently `getCalendarUriBase()` is flawed. Since there is no such method in Android, presumably you wrote this yourself. So, you will need to determine what it is returning. The error suggests that it is using `content://calendar`, and that's certainly not the correct value for `CalendarContract`, and I don't recall that being correct even for the undocumented/unsupported calendar `ContentProvider` from earlier versions of Android.